# Cómo formar un link si gmail no acepta javascript

Tags: html, css

Necesito construir un link apenas llegue al correo **pero gmail no permite usar javascript**, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo usando html puro?

```js
var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
var txt2 = document.getElementById("txt2");

var link = document.getElementById("link");

link.src = txt1.innerText + txt2.innerText;
```

```html
<div class="content">

<p id="txt1">https://www.ejemplo.com/</p>
<p id="txt2">index.php</p>

<a id="link">Ir</a>

</div>
```

Comment: es un solo enlace o múltiples?

Comment: @BetaM solo uno pero pues cogiendo datos de varios <p>

Comment: Porqué usas el atributo `src` y no usas el atributo [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/link#Atributos)?

Comment: Por otro lado, Gmail (así como muchos otros servicios de email) no te permitirá nunca ejecutar el código que escribas dentro de una etiqueta `<script>`. Por lo tanto, no existe forma o manera (usando sólo HTML y/o CSS) de modificar el atributo `href` de un elemento del DOM. No tiene sentido enviar código Javascript en un mensaje de correo electrónico. Saludos

Comment: Quedaré pendiente a la solución de esta respuesta, agradezco la observación @MauricioContreras :)

Comment: porque no creas el link cuando generas el html del mail en el server?